# Facebook og:image uses the wrong picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have some trouble with the picture that Facebook uses when people share posts for my website on Facebook.

When I use the Facebook debug tool you see at the bottom of the page the right picture that needs to be used on Facebook, but when you go to the Facebook post you see an other picture (the first picture on the debug page at the og:image tag). But that picture doesn't have the go:image meta tag, and the post picture is minimal 200x200 px: http://www.just40.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Dollarphotoclub_68950691-1024x712.jpg

Facebook debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.just40.nl%2Fbloggers%2Fgood-old-smoking-days-dees-12%2F

How can I fix this?

Comment: Start with fixing the error the debugger gives you: "Your page has meta tags in the body instead of the head. This may be because your HTML was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the thing that's removed the <head> tag from the page. My customer add this by her own for the new Facebook API at the top of the header.php file and distorted the head for the Facebook parser.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

see how the parser see your page [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.just40.nl%2Fbloggers%2Fgood-old-smoking-days-dees-12%2F) .

**Now fix the following errors**

1. `og` tags are supposed be in the `head` section of the page html.If it doesn't find it there, it will infer it according to its own liking.yours are in body tag

[image]

2. your page contains multiple occurrences of `og:image` . fix that .

[image]